# Open Excel application without new workbook

Tags: c#, excel

I need to open an excel app without a new book in there. Is it possible? Here is my code:

```
public static Excel.Application InitializeTemplateExcelApp(string logFile)
{
            Excel.Application app = null;

            try
            {
                app = new Excel.Application();
                app.Visible = true;
                // reload all previously loaded addins

                foreach (Excel.AddIn ai in app.AddIns)
                {
                    if (ai.Installed != false)
                    {
                        ai.Installed = false;
                        ai.Installed = true;

                        app.Wait(30);
                    }
                }

                return app;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errMessage = ex.Message.ToString();
                File.AppendAllText(logFile, errMessage);
                return null;
            }

        }
```

The problem is when I initialize excel app the new workbook created automatically. After that I need to open my own workbook which already becomes a second one opened and I want to avoid this.

Thanks for your help,

Ilya

Comment: Why not just launch the process excel.exe directly? It should not open a workbook by default.

Comment: Interesting, but if I simply run excel.exe it actually open new book as well... may be it is some excel properties? Plus I need to make sure that all addins that were previously installed still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running this command before setting the application to visible

```
app.ActiveWorkbook.Close(false);
app.visible = true;
```

That should close the active workbook before showing the user anything.

Answer (score 1):

Your other option is to start `excel.exe` with command line arguments.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/command-line-switches-for-excel-HA010158030.aspx#BM4

Comment: sorry, I need to open it in C# module

Answer (score 0):

I believe Excel will open a workbook using a default template.
Just close all open workbooks before opening your own.

Comment: Agree that is one way, just wanted to know if there is an option not to write any extra code...