# How to open an existing workbook without creating an new book?

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I want to open and edit an excel workbook. However, when I run the following, it always create a new book (Book1) which I don't want.

```
import xlwings as xw

mypath= #path
app= xw.App()
wb=app.books.open(mypath)
```

After running, there will always be an unnecessary new Book1 created. Is there anyway to make it tidier?

I tried replacing app=xw.App() with app=xw.App(add_book=False), but it shows error below:

```
    raise XlwingsError("Couldn't find any active App!")
xlwings.XlwingsError: Couldn't find any active App!
```

I also tried removing the line app=xw.App() and directly open the book with

```
wb=xw.books.open(mypath)
```

If I already have an excel file opened, then this worked as I wish, opened the book with any new book created. But if there is no other excel file opened, then the same error as above is raised.

Also tried the following from previous questions. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11018237/open-excel-application-without-new-workbook](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

```
import xlwings as xw

mypath= #path
app= xw.App()
app.ActiveWorkbook.Close(False);
app.visible = True;
wb=app.books.open(mypath)
```

Error occured

```
    app.ActiveWorkbook.Close(False);
AttributeError: 'App' object has no attribute 'ActiveWorkbook'
```

This seems to be a very simple question, please bear me since I am very new to Python (and xlwings) and this is my first time asking questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to use a context manager since it cleans up nicely at close.

```
import xlwings as xw


workbook = 'Book1.xlsx'

with xw.App() as app:
    wb = xw.Book(workbook)
    ws = wb.sheets('Sheet1')

    ...


    wb.save(workbook)  # needed only if data is written to the workbook
    wb.close()
```

##----------------------------##
[image: xlwings run]

##----------------------------##

```
import xlwings as xw


workbook = 'yourExcelFile.xlsm'

with xw.App(visible=False, add_book=False) as app:
    wb = xw.Book(workbook)
    ws = wb.sheets('Sheet1')

    # ...
    print(ws.range('A1').value)

    wb.save(workbook)  # <-- Needed only where sheet data changed

    wb.app.quit()
```

Comment: During runtime it still creates a new book, just looking for a way to avoid this. This is not a big problem, just me feeling I have little control over my program.

Comment: It will only open the existing Excel file 'Book1.xlsx'.  If 'Book1.xlsx' does not exist you will get a **File Not Found Error**, it won't create a new 'workbook'. 'wb' will be an object referring to the excel file that the variable 'workbook' points to. If I enter 'Hello' in cell 'A1' in Book1.xlsx (save and close the workbook) then put **print(ws.range('A1').value)** where the three dots are in the example it will print out the value in cell A1 i.e. 'Hello' Maybe you are being confused as there likely will be two Excel instances opened while the code is running.

Comment: I tried your code, and replaced 'Book1.xlsx' with the full name of my excel file (the extension is .xlsm, if this matters). A new workbook is created and my excel is opened. For the "two Excel instances opened ", I'm not very sure. I just called xw.App() once only, why will there be two instances?

Comment: Makes no difference if its a macro enabled workbook. Are you seeing something like the image in the answer above where your workbook (here called yourExcelFile.xlsm) is opened and another workbook (in this case called 'Book1') is also opened? If so that is from xlwings app, you can ignore it and it will be closed when the code ends.
If you want you can set the line **with xw.App() as app:** to **with xw.App(visible=False) as app:** and you should not see any Excel instances opened, or don't use App.

Comment: Yes, yourExcelFile.xlsm is opened plus a new workbook (with Excel's default name Book1.xlsm). In your comment, seems that this could not be avoided.

Comment: If your experience is as shown in the image, its not 'Book1.xlsm' just 'Book1'. As my previous comment metions you can avoid it by setting visible to False so you don't see any Excel instances or do not use app i.e. remove line **with xw.App() as app:** (and unindent the rest of the code).

Comment: Yes, your image is exactly what I encountered. Setting the visible to False worked as you say, no excel window is visible. I can live with that, but is there a way to make the "Book1" invisible while keeping my own workbook visible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try with the added code example. This should only show the opened wb and exit Excel on close.

Comment: Now tested, `with xw.App(add_book=False):` unfortunately also opens a second Excel window (the only difference is that it is empty, i.e. without a workbook inside). The documentation could definitely be improved with regards to the parameter `add_book` of the function `xw.App()`. Currently, this parameter is not described in the documentation, see: https://docs.xlwings.org/en/latest/api/app.html#xlwings.App

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if they added this in a recent update (seeing that the question was not asked too long ago), but:

```
import xlwings as xw

app = xw.App(visible=False, add_book=False) # works with visible=False as well
wb = app.books.open("path/to/book")
app.visible = True # check if the book is actually opened

app.quit() # be sure to close the app, otherwise the excel process will keep running
```

For me, this will open an empty excel instance (no book opened in it) and then load the book I want to open in that window. So for anyone searching for this issue: It might be worth a try; this working might as well be a change in the xlwings functionality as well as just be dependant on Excel settings. Since https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/1545 is not closed at the time of this answer and the documentation not mentioning the add_book attribute at all, be wary of this changing without notice in the future though.

This works also with the context manager approach moken proposed.

Answer (score 0):

```
import xlwings as xw
#opens instance invisible
app = xw.App(visible=False)

book = xw.apps[app.pid].books.open(filepath)
###do stuff
book.save()
book.close
app.quit()
```

This works for me perfectly. It opens a new excel instance and only uses this instance for the changes by Python. Like this i can open a manual instance where i can work while the program is Running without interfering with it.