# Avoid opening a new workbook when using xlwings

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I am using `xlwings` to edit a number of workbooks. According to the documentation, `App()` "should normally be used as context manager to make sure that everything is properly cleaned up again". I take that to mean that you should open the other workbooks within the `App()` context manager. However, when I initiate an instance of excel using `xw.App()`, it opens 'Book1' initially.

This isn't a massive problem as it closes once the other code has run, but I would like to avoid this new workbook opening if possible.

```
import xlwings as xw

with xw.App() as APP:
    for book in APP.books:
        print(book.name)
    # Iterate through and edit other workbooks here.....
```

Comment: I had some discussion on this previously in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74297604/how-to-open-an-existing-workbook-without-creating-an-new-book/74298944#74298944) that you might find useful.

Comment: Thanks @moken. From your comments it seems that you can't avoid opening a new book when using App as a context manager. In that case I think I will avoid using App and instead open and close each book in my for loop.