# xlwings not opening in background

Tags: python, excel, background, openpyxl, xlwings

Can anyone explain why this code opens 2 Excel instances? From what I have observed `app = xw.App(visible=True)` opens a new excel file which I can manipulate if I want to hide it in the background, but `wb = app.books.open(file_path)` opens in a new instance which I cannot hide ...

Also it is important to note that the code is supposed to change a few cells colors in an xlsx file that is shared on a network drive. At the same time many users can use the Excel file.

```
def done_id(file_path, id_to_color):
    try:
        # Otwieranie pliku Excel w tle
        app = xw.App(visible=True) # True for tests to see the 2nd instance
        wb = app.books.open(file_path)
        sheet = wb.sheets['LISTA']

        # Przeszukiwanie kolumny B w poszukiwaniu ID i kolorowanie wiersza
        for row in range(3, sheet.range('B' + str(sheet.cells.last_cell.row)).end('up').row + 1):
            if sheet.range('B' + str(row)).value == id_to_color:
                sheet.range('B' + str(row)).color = (0, 255, 0)  # Ustawienie koloru zielonego

        # Zapisanie zmian i zamknięcie pliku
        wb.save()
        wb.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Błąd: {e}")
    finally:
        # Zamknięcie aplikacji Excel
        app.quit()
```

I have tried also using different libraries like win32com.client with VBA, openpyxl but none worked.

win32com.client with VBA cannot run on shared files.

openpyxl stops the sharing of the document.

From what I have heard there is no library that can possibly solve my problem but maybe someone can enlighten me.

Comment: This may not be a 2nd instance but rather a 2nd window in the same instance. Since a few years or versions, respectively, Excel opens new workbooks in separate window. Check the task manager to see the number of instances.

Comment: Thank you for a fast response. I did see if I have an opened excels in task manager, as sometimes some dont close if an error occurs. But this in not the root of the problem. This code dont seem to cause this problem, but rather I am just unable to open this excel workbook in background...

Comment: Have you tried working with context manager? Maybe this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74297604/how-to-open-an-existing-workbook-without-creating-an-new-book/74298944#74298944) might be worth looking at as it investigates some circumstances for Excel instances being opened with Xlwings

Comment: This doesnt change anything still 2 Excel windows open in which the empty one I can hide.